# Constraint to enforce that there can be at most 2 instances of a value (or set of values)

Tags: sql-server

A unique index can be used to ensure that there is at most 1 instance of a particular value or set of values. My question is, is there a way to enforce that there be at most 2 instances of a value or set of values? I am aware of triggers and scalar UDFs in check constraints. I'm not interested in those solutions.

Database: SQL Server 2017.

Comment: "*I am aware of triggers and scalar UDFs in check constraints. I'm not interested in those solutions.*" - Why?

Comment: Scalar UDFs in check constraints prevent parallelism. Triggers are not simple enough for me to be sure they will work reliably.

Comment: Only way I can think of would be to add a `BIT NOT NULL` column and include that in the unique constraint. Your application would be responsible for finding out if `0` or `1` is a free slot though and managing that part but the system would at least guarantee the constraint

Comment: @user23278799 FWIW, check constraints don't need to only use non-inlinable scalar functions. Constraints can be defined on any applicable expression. Such expression can potentially be done in a way that doesn't inhibit parallelism. As far as triggers go, you shouldn't necessarily preclude yourself from using a technology or feature, just because you don't know how it works. Triggers are definitely worth learning and some experts recommend them as a more efficient and reliable replacement for constraints and even foreign keys.

Comment: @J.D. I understand how triggers work. That's why I don't want to use them.

Comment: @user23278799 Not sure I follow your original statement "*Triggers are not simple enough for me to be sure they will work reliably*" then. Are you afraid of the reliability of triggers as a feature or reliability of your ability to code them properly?...because with the former, they're as reliable as the original DML statement itself, when coded properly. They execute under the same transaction. Can't have one without the other.

Comment: @J.D. My database has trigger recursion disabled, which means an update made to the table from within the trigger will not be validated. To fix, i could have a separate trigger just containing the validation code. Problem there is that, if someone disables the nested triggers option, then the validation code won't run. It's too flaky.

Comment: @user23278799 Why would the validation code produce invalid results? That seems like a code problem, not a trigger problem. "*Problem there is that, if someone disables the nested triggers option*" - Sure, if any developer undoes what you do to solve this problem, then you still have a problem. That's regardless of using triggers. ‍♂️

Comment: @J.D. Let's say the trigger containing the validation code has other code in it that updates the same table, for example to set the last modified date to the current date. That update itself must also be validated.   Regarding nested triggers, no one would think that it would stop the validation code from running for an update done in a trigger. It's brittle.

Comment: @user23278799 "*That update itself must also be validated.*" - As it should, within the scope of the same initial execution of the trigger, at the time that update occurs. It would be silly in the trigger, which validates data changes, to be able to create more invalid data changes. If you need to refactor the validation logic of the trigger into a procedure, function, CTE, etc, so be it. But it shouldn't be possible for your context to leave the validation trigger with unvalidated data. That's a design issue then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a column with a check constraint on it only allowing numbers between `0` and `1`.

Then simply put a unique key on that.

```
CREATE TABLE YourTable (
    SetId int,
    IdInSet int CONSTRAINT Max2PerSet CHECK (IdInset BETWEEN 0 AND 1),
    PRIMARY KEY (SetId, IdInSet)
);
```

You would have to check for an open slot in each set before you made an update or delete. Don't consider the extra column to be consecutive, it's not worth it, just look for a free ID in that set.